# t function in R. It's not coming out the way it looks

Tags: r, tapply

I have a question about `t` function in R.

I used the `tapply` function to get the septal length of iris' species.
But why does the `t` function have the same result like this?

[image]

I guessed that if I use t function in "A",
code would show like this

```
setosa        5.006
versicolor    5.936
virginica     6.588
```

Comment: you can double transpose `t(t(A))` or use `stack(A)`

Answer (score 0):

`A` is just a vector, which is 1-dimensional, so it's not really a row or a column.

In order to transpose it with `t()`, it has to be converted to a matrix, which is 2-dimensional. By default, R treats vectors as columns when converting to a matrix. So `as.matrix()` gives a column, and transposing that gives a row. For example:

```
> x = c(1, 2, 3)
> as.matrix(x)
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3
> t(x)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code produces a vector with names for each element.

```
A <- (tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, mean))
str(A)
# num [1:3(1d)] 5.01 5.94 6.59
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
#  ..$ : chr [1:3] "setosa" "versicolor" "virginica"
```

If you put your vector into a 2d form like a dataframe or a matrix, it would be shown vertically. The transposition converts it to horizontal like your example.

```
data.frame(A)
               A
setosa     5.006
versicolor 5.936
virginica  6.588


data.frame(t(A))
  setosa versicolor virginica
1  5.006      5.936     6.588
```